# Why doesn't Laravel Vapor inject ASSET_URL in my build step?

Tags: laravel, webpack, github-actions, laravel-mix, laravel-vapor

I am literally copying what the Laravel Vapor documentation states but to no avail. So to keep it short, I am unable to access the `ASSET_URL` environment variable that Taylor says is injected during the build step.

Now note, the same environment variable is being injected into the application which is why the `assets()` and `mix()` helpers in blade on index.blade.php work just fine. However, my problem is accessing the `ASSET_URL` inside `webpack.mix.js`.

This is from my Github action below. You can see that `ASSET_URL` is empty when logged.

```
> @ production /github/workspace/.vapor/build/app
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

ASSET URL IS: 
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 26754ms11:23:07 PM
```

**webpack.mix.js.**

```
// To deal with Laravel Vapor
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    const ASSET_URL = process.env.ASSET_URL;
    console.log("ASSET URL IS: " + ASSET_URL);

    mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
        return {
            plugins: [
                new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    "process.env.ASSET_PATH": JSON.stringify(ASSET_URL)
                })
            ],
            output: {
                publicPath: ASSET_URL
            }
        };
    });
```

**Proposed solutions on Laracasts forums**

1. Paul Marshall suggests that he found a workaround by using `window.__ASSET_URL__ = '{{ env('ASSET_URL') }}';` but I do not like that approach, unless its the last resort.
2. @fylzero suggests that I do `MIX_ASSET_URL="${ASSET_URL}"` in my environment files to see if Mix can read that. It doesn't.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having a similar issue trying to deploy on vapor over a github action. During the build step, a `.env` file is created, the `ASSET_URL` is properly injected, but it just won't source the file (even `export $(xargs < .env)` at the beginnging of the build step won't work). Using the `ASSET_URL` will always yield an empty ENV.

Comment: It may be caused by a security feature for the github action. An env variable may be set in a step, but can only be accessed in the next step.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we think it relates to [github not sourcing the `.env` file](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable). The env file, it contains the right content, but even manually sourcing the `.env` file does not work, as apparently the `env` variables only become available in the next step.

We have fallen back on manually parsing the env variable out of the `.env` file, we used this grep approach:

```
$(grep -oP "ASSET_URL=\K.*$" .env)
```